# remove first line from string builder / string c#

Tags: c#, stringbuilder

Okay so I'm trying to make a 'console' like text box within a form, however once you reach the bottom, instaid of being able to scroll up, it will just delete the top line, Im having some difficulties.
So far, when it gets to bottom it deletes the top line, however only once, it just carries on as normal. Here is my function:

```
   StringBuilder sr = new StringBuilder();
    public void writeLine(string input)
    {
        string firstline = "";
        int numLines = Convert.ToString(sr).Split('\n').Length;
        if (numLines > 15)      //Max Lines
        {                
            sr.Remove(0, Convert.ToString(sr).Split('\n').FirstOrDefault().Length);              
        }
        sr.Append(input + "\r\n");
        consoleTxtBox.Text = Convert.ToString(sr) + numLines;
    }
```

Would be great if someone could fix this, thanks

Lucas

Comment: StringBuilder is not the correct datastructure for this. You need an array of 15 strings and shift the strings as need. A fixed size queue could work too.

Comment: Cheers, i dont know why I didnt think of that in the first place

Comment: Well the only problem I would have with this would be each time I create a new input it will have to write out all other previous lines iswell?

Answer (score 11):

First, what's wrong with your solution: the reason it does not work is that it removes the content of the line, but it ignores the `\n` at the end. Adding `1` should fix that:

```
sr.Remove(0, Convert.ToString(sr).Split('\n').FirstOrDefault().Length+1);              
//                                                                    ^
//                                                                    |
//   This will take care of the trailing '\n' after the first line ---+
```

Now to doing it a simpler way: all you need to do is finding the first `\n`, and taking substring after it, like this:

```
string RemoveFirstLine(string s) {
    return s.Substring(s.IndexOf(Environment.NewLine)+1);
}
```

Note that this code does not crash even when there are no newline characters in the string, i.e. when `IndexOf` returns `-1` (in which case nothing is removed).

Comment: @user2294174 You are welcome! If this solves your problem, consider accepting the answer by clicking the check mark next to it. This would let others know that you are no longer looking for an improved solution to the problem, and earn you a badge on stack overflow.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [Lines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.lines.aspx) property from the TextBox. This will get all the lines in the TextBox, as an array, then create a new array that doesn't include the first element (`Skip(1)`). It assigns this new array back to the textbox.

```
string[] lines = textBox.Lines;
textBox.Lines = lines.Skip(1).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 2):

A simple alternative: you could split the string by `Environment.NewLine` and return all but the first:

```
public static string RemoveFirstLine(string input)
{
    var lines = input.Split(new[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None);
    return string.Join(Environment.NewLine, lines.Skip(1));
}
```

[**Demo**](http://ideone.com/Xh9usV)

Comment: @user2294174: Is that a question? I've added a demo, so you can see that it works. You have to reassign the returned string. `Strings` are immutable, so you cannot modify them.  See my demo.

Answer (score 2):

you can remove this line

```
 var lines = lines.Remove(0, lines.ToString().IndexOf(Environment.NewLine));
```

Comment: This will not remove \r\n, meaning will leave first empty line.

Answer (score 1):

Most solutions does not seem to take into account the fact that Enviroment.NewLine can consist of multiple characters (len > 1).

```
    public void RemoveFirstStringFromStringBuilder()
    {
        var lines = new StringBuilder();

        lines.AppendLine("abc");

        var firstLine = lines.ToString().IndexOf(Environment.NewLine, StringComparison.Ordinal);

        if (firstLine >= 0)
            lines.Remove(0, firstLine + Environment.NewLine.Length);

        Console.WriteLine(lines.Length);
        Console.WriteLine(lines.ToString());
    }
```

Prints out: 0 and ""

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me is:

```
    var strBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    strBuilder.AppendLine("ABC");
    strBuilder.AppendLine("54");
    strBuilder.AppendLine("04");

    strBuilder.Remove(0, strBuilder.ToString().IndexOf(Environment.NewLine) + 2);

    Console.WriteLine(strBuilder);
```

Solution with +1 didn't work for me, probably because of EOF in this context being interpreted as 2 chars (\r\n)

Answer (score 0):

Removing just the first line is a poor solution. What if you append multiple lines at once separated by NewLines? The following is a better approach, where the code ensures that there is at most a certain number of lines:

```
public int maxLines = 50;

public void RemoveSuperfluousLines(ref string text)
{
    // A line is defined by the NewLine sequence. Match all NewLines in the text.
    MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(text, Environment.NewLine);
    // Find the index of the match directly preceding the first line we want to allow.
    int index = matches.Count - maxLines;
    // A negative index means we have less than maxLines number of lines.
    if (index >= 0)
        // Remove everything up to and including the match.
        text = text.Remove(0, matches[index].Index + matches[index].Length);
}

public void AppendLine(ref string text, string line)
{
    // Append the line preceded by a NewLine to the text.
    text = text + Environment.NewLine + line;
    // Remove superfluous lines.
    RemoveSuperfluousLines(ref text);
}
```

Usage:

```
maxLines = 15;

// Write more than 15 lines, lol!
for (int index = 0; index < 50; index++)
{
    AppendLine(ref text, index.ToString());
}

consoleTxtBox.Text = text;
```

Answer (score 0):

This version is efficent and handles all possible variations of new-line characters ("\r\n", "\r", "\n").

```cs
char[] NewLineChars = { '\r', '\n' };

string RemoveFirstLine(string s)
{
    int i = s.IndexOfAny(NewLineChars);
    if (i < 0)
        return s;
    char c = s[i++];
    if (c == NewLineChars[0] && i < s.Length && s[i] == NewLineChars[1])
        i++;
    return s.Substring(i);
}
```